# Data Lake Analytics Query Fails

Tags: json, azure, stream, analytics, iot

Data Lake Analytics job failed with the following error with input as json file. Looks like a json formatting error. Any help is greatly appreciated.
The json file was generated by stream analytics with data from IOT hub as input.

{
    "jobId": "https://iotdla4c2c5a3b.azuredatalakeanalytics.net/jobLink/4eddd130-e0fc-45d4-8b3a-179b0e49f6c1",
    "errors": {
        "diagnosticCode": 195887158,
        "severity": "Error",
        "component": "RUNTIME",
        "source": "User",
        "errorId": "E_RUNTIME_USER_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION_FROM_USER_CODE",
        "message": "An unhandled exception from user code has been reported when invoking the method 'Extract' on the user type 'Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor'",
        "description": "Unhandled exception from user code: \"Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0.\"\nThe details includes more information including any inner exceptions and the stack trace where the exception was raised.",
        "resolution": "Make sure the bug in the user code is fixed.",
        "helpLink": "",
        "details": "==== Caught exception Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException\n\n   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()\r\n   at Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n   at ScopeEngine.RunUdoCodeExceptionhandled >(ScopeTypedManagedHandle* className, SByte* methodName, * code) in d:\data\yarnnm\local\usercache\9bb5486e-cb76-464b-a635-28243eb11fb0\appcache\application_1556746128054_0157\container_e391_1556746128054_0157_01_000001\wd\managed.h:line 2034",
        "userData": ""
    }
}

Comment: Does `Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content: {. Path '', line 2, position 0.\"\n` not give enough details? Seem like your input json is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

DataLake stores json in two different formats. 1. line Feed. 2 Array. Changing the format to Array solved this problem

Comment: Please accept as an answer it will other who have the same ask.